# ImportString JSON possible bug

Tags: bugs, import, json-format

My problem is when I catch up some `json` output of  whatever method and process it with `ImportString[%, "JSON"]`, The first time when it executes, it works and then without doing anything, it stops working, and an error appears forever in the session. Then, I should restart Mathematica.

```
Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as JSON format. >>
```

For example, I could try with `URLFetch`, you could use other like `ServiceExecute` , I saw that other guys get the same errors.

```
URLFetch["https://api.twitter.com/1.1/application/rate_limit_status.\
    json?resources=search", 
        "Method" -> "GET",
        "Headers" -> { "Authorization" -> "Bearer " <> $token}
      ]
```

Out:

```
"{\"rate_limit_context\":{\"application\":\"ZIfS6A0hLFFGn0rTK8AA\"},\"\
resources\":{\"search\":{\"\\/search\\/tweets\":{\"limit\":450,\"\
remaining\":441,\"reset\":1417461650}}}}"
```

Using `ImportString[%, "JSON"]`

```
{"resources" -> {"search" -> {"/search/tweets" -> {"reset" -> 
        1417464421, "limit" -> 450, "remaining" -> 450}}}, 
 "rate_limit_context" -> {"application" -> "ZIfS6A0hLFFGn0rTK8AA"}}
```

And in an unexpected way, if I try the same:

```
Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as JSON format. >>
```

After that, all functions that can process `JSON` stop working.
Any idea?

**UPDATE:** 
If you can reproduce my current problem in a real example. I'm doing the next:

```
   $token = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACIzUwAAAAAAIcK0ag%2BYQgJMWChjJFIOvC3oBc0%3DPSlfWyj98uQTquGq9oBuVwVovUCfKuOwHSpSSIvMZSJeBRsbQD";
```

The next function use `ImportString` and sometimes it fails.

```
Clear[buscarTuits];
buscarTuits[expr_Association:{}] := Module[
{query, res},
    query =  URLBuild["https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json", expr];
    res = ImportString[URLFetch[query, 
        "Method"-> "GET",
        "Headers"-> { "Authorization"-> "Bearer "<>$token}], "JSON"]; 
    Return[res];
];

buscarTuits[expr_String]:= buscarTuits[Association["q"-> expr]];
```

And,

```
buscarTuits["wolfram"]
```

Sometimes appear the next error and others times don't.

```
Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as JSON format. >>
```

This Bug after all discussion here. It was notified to **Wolfram Support**  **[CASE:1884981]**. 
I'll update this post in the future with the responses by support assistance .

Comment: Version Mathematica 10

Comment: This time, it works for me, :(   {"search_metadata" -> {"since_id" -> 0, "count" -> 15, 
   "max_id_str" -> "539548678797922304", 
   "refresh_url" -> 
    "?since_id=539548678797922304&q= nixpxon&include_entities=1", 
   "completed_in" -> 0.018, "max_ id" -> 539548678797922304, 
   "query " -> "nixpxon", "since_id_ str" -> "0"}, "statuses" -> {}}

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The simplest case I found so far is:  `ImportString["{\"data\":2}", "JSON"]`, which is valid JSON, but doesn't import for me in V10. However, **it works in v8 and v9, so this seems to be a bug in v10**

Comment: Works for me. {"data" -> 2}

Comment: You are right. On a fresh kernel it works for me too. But this illustrates nicely the phenomenon that you described, i.e. that once it failed everything JSON keeps failing

Comment: It looks like the size of the JSON string may be a factor. I found that sizes of 7KB and below import fine but ones above 35KB yield the error.

Comment: The critical boundary is somewhere between 33 and 35 kB.

Comment: Yes!, after some many tries, it stop working with `buscarTuits[<| "q" -> "uribe", "count" -> 100 |> ]` that is certainly > 20KB.

Comment: @jonaprieto Did you even get an update from Wolfram Support on the bug report you filed? Is this still relevant to later versions of MMA?

Comment: @jonaprieto could you replace code in the question with examples shown here? Let's clean up a little.